# FCM Maximum message rate to a single device

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

per https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#device_throttling, it says...

> You can send up to 240 messages/minute and 5,000 messages/hour to a single device. This high threshold is meant to allow for short term bursts of traffic, such as when users are interacting rapidly over chat. This limit prevents errors in sending logic from inadvertently draining the battery on a device.

does this mean a device can only receive 240 messages / minute?
or does it mean it can receive 240 messages sent by a particular device?

say, 4 other devices can send 240 messages to a device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limit on the number of downstream messages that can be sent **to** a device for the entire project.

Sending messages **to** a device should only happen from a trusted environment (your development machine, the Firebase console, a server you control, Cloud Functions). There is no ability to send downstream messages with the Firebase client-side SDKs.

Comment: does this apply to messages received from topics?

Comment: I tihnk so. It's messages to a device, so messages so topics that are delivered to that device also count.